# Manifest merger failed : Attribute provider

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Manifest merger failed : Attribute provider#droidninja.filepicker.utils.FilePickerProvider@authorities

value=(com.xxx.xxx.droidninja.filepicker.provider) from AndroidManifest.xml:85:13-88
is also present at [com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.1] AndroidManifest.xml:26:13-82

value=(com.xxx.xxx.droidninja.filepicker.provider).

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:83:9-93:20 to override.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class that extends  FileProvider

```
public class MyProvider extends FileProvider 
{ 
   
}
```

and inside your Manifest define your provider.

```
<provider android:name=".MyProvider"/>
```